# Fast exact algorithm for subset sum problem in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have implemented an \$\mathcal{O}(N2^{N/2})\$ algorithm for subset sum problem described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

That is what I have:

**SubsetSumFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.combinatorics;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * This interface defines the API for a subset sum algorithm.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 25, 2016)
 */
public interface SubsetSumFinder {

    /**
     * Attempts to find a subset of {@code data}, such that all integers in the
     * subset sum to {@code sum}.
     * 
     * @param data the list of integers.
     * @param sum  the requested sum.
     * @return a subset summing to {@code sum} or {@code null} if there is no 
     *         such.
     */
    public List<Integer> findSubsetWithSum(final List<Integer> data, 
                                           final int sum);
}
```

**CombinationIterable.java** (already reviewed):

```
package net.coderodde.combinatorics.support;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class CombinationIterable<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {

    private final List<T> allElements;

    public CombinationIterable(List<T> allElements) {
        this.allElements = new ArrayList<>(allElements);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
        return new CombinationIterator<>(allElements);
    }

    private static final class CombinationIterator<T> 
    implements Iterator<List<T>> {

        private final List<T> allElements;
        private final int[] indices;
        private List<T> nextCombination;
        private int currentCombinationSize;

        CombinationIterator(List<T> allElements) {
            this.allElements = new ArrayList<>(allElements);
            this.indices = new int[allElements.size()];

            if (!allElements.isEmpty()) {
                // Create the first combination.
                currentCombinationSize = 1;
                nextCombination = new ArrayList<>(1);
                nextCombination.add(allElements.get(0));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextCombination != null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<T> next() {
            if (nextCombination == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No combinations left.");
            }

            List<T> combination = nextCombination;
            generateNextCombination();
            return combination;
        }

        private void loadCombination() {
            List<T> combination = new ArrayList<>(currentCombinationSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < currentCombinationSize; ++i) {
                combination.add(allElements.get(indices[i]));
            }

            this.nextCombination = combination;
        }

        private void generateNextCombination() {
            if (indices[currentCombinationSize - 1] < indices.length - 1) {
                indices[currentCombinationSize - 1]++;
                loadCombination();
                return;
            }

            for (int i = currentCombinationSize - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (indices[i] < indices[i + 1] - 1) {
                    indices[i]++;

                    for (int j = i + 1; j < currentCombinationSize; ++j) {
                        indices[j] = indices[j - 1] + 1;
                    }

                    loadCombination();
                    return;
                }
            }

            ++currentCombinationSize;

            if (currentCombinationSize > indices.length) {
                this.nextCombination = null;
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < currentCombinationSize; ++i) {
                indices[i] = i;
            }

            loadCombination();
        }
    }
}
```

**FastSubsetSumFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.combinatorics.support;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import net.coderodde.combinatorics.SubsetSumFinder;

/**
 * This class implements a faster exact subset sum algorithm.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 25, 2016)
 */
public class FastSubsetSumFinder implements SubsetSumFinder {

    @Override
    public List<Integer> findSubsetWithSum(List<Integer> data, int sum) {
        final List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        final int size = data.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; ++i) {
            list1.add(data.get(i));
        }

        for (int i = size / 2; i < size; ++i) {
            list2.add(data.get(i));
        }

        final List<List<Integer>> combinationList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<List<Integer>> combinationList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        final Map<List<Integer>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (final List<Integer> subset : new CombinationIterable<>(list1)) {
            map.put(subset, sum(subset));
            combinationList1.add(subset);
        }

        for (final List<Integer> subset : new CombinationIterable<>(list2)) {
            map.put(subset, sum(subset));
            combinationList2.add(subset);
        }

        final Comparator<List<Integer>> comparator = new SubsetComparator(map);

        Collections.sort(combinationList1, comparator);
        Collections.sort(combinationList2, comparator);

        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = combinationList2.size() - 1;

        while (true) {
            int totalSum = map.get(combinationList1.get(index1)) +
                           map.get(combinationList2.get(index2));

            if (totalSum < sum) {
                ++index1;
            } else if (totalSum > sum) {
                --index2;
            } else {
                final List<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<>(size);
                solution.addAll(combinationList1.get(index1));
                solution.addAll(combinationList2.get(index2));
                return solution;
            }

            if (index1 == combinationList1.size() 
                    || index2 == -1) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private int sum(final List<Integer> subset) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (final Integer i : subset) {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private static final class SubsetComparator 
    implements Comparator<List<Integer>> {

        private final Map<List<Integer>, Integer> map;

        SubsetComparator(final Map<List<Integer>, Integer> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
            final int sum1 = map.get(o1);
            final int sum2 = map.get(o2);
            return Integer.compare(sum1, sum2);
        }
    }
}
```

**NaiveSubsetSumFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.combinatorics.support;

import java.util.List;
import net.coderodde.combinatorics.SubsetSumFinder;

/**
 * This class implements a naive exact algorithm for solving the subset sum 
 * problem.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 25, 2016)
 */
public class NaiveSubsetSumFinder implements SubsetSumFinder {

    @Override
    public List<Integer> findSubsetWithSum(List<Integer> data, int sum) {
        final CombinationIterable<Integer> iterable = 
                new CombinationIterable<>(data);

        for (final List<Integer> subset : iterable) {
            if (sum(subset) == sum) {
                return subset;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private int sum(final List<Integer> subset) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (final Integer integer : subset) {
            sum += integer;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import net.coderodde.combinatorics.SubsetSumFinder;
import net.coderodde.combinatorics.support.FastSubsetSumFinder;
import net.coderodde.combinatorics.support.NaiveSubsetSumFinder;

public class Demo {

    private static final int N = 25;
    private static final int N_INTEGERS = 100;
    private static final int NEEDLE = 1000;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final long seed = System.nanoTime();
        final Random random = new Random(seed);
        final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>(N);

        System.out.println("Seed = " + seed);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            data.add(random.nextInt(N_INTEGERS));
        }

        final SubsetSumFinder finderNaive = new NaiveSubsetSumFinder();
        final SubsetSumFinder finderFast  = new FastSubsetSumFinder();

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        final List<Integer> subset1 = 
                finderNaive.findSubsetWithSum(data, NEEDLE);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf("NaiveSubsetSumFinder: %5.0f milliseconds. " +
                          "Result: %s, valid: %b.\n",
                          (endTime - startTime) / 1e6,
                          subset1,
                          sum(subset1) == NEEDLE);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        final List<Integer> subset2 = 
                finderFast.findSubsetWithSum(data, NEEDLE);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf("FastSubsetSumFinder:  %5.0f milliseconds. " +
                          "Result: %s, valid: %b.\n",
                          (endTime - startTime) / 1e6,
                          subset2,
                          sum(subset2) == NEEDLE);
    }

    private static int sum(final List<Integer> subset) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (final Integer i : subset) {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

The performance figures are as follows:

```
NaiveSubsetSumFinder:  3371 milliseconds.
FastSubsetSumFinder:    115 milliseconds.
```

Any critique much appreciated.

Comment: I can see from your numbers that Fast is actually faster than naive, but your perf testing technique is flawed. Java heavily optimises code as it executes, so you need to run through your code quite a lot to allow the jvm to complete doing that before you start measuring performance.

Comment: Yeah, I know: the warmup effect. In case you don't trust the figures, roll your own warmup code (I am not sure whether it is O.K. to edit the question). However, I am confident that the **`Fast`** implementation has better time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

I found a case that needs some attention.

The naive version works with following, but the fast version does not:

- data = "1,3,8,10,20"
- answer = 18

Comment: Can you help the OP fix it?